# Lower bound on $k$ when $(1-\varepsilon )^k < \frac{3}{4n}$

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, upper-lower-bounds

I try to found Lower bound on $k$ when $(1-\varepsilon )^k < \frac{3}{4n}$.
The lower bound should be $k=\Omega(\log{n})$ but I can't find a way to prove that... I tried to use Bernoulli's inequality but the result was not good enough I also tried to proved using combinatorics methods but that also failed.
Anyone got an idea?

Thanks

Edit: $\varepsilon$ is constant s.t. $0<\varepsilon<1$

Comment: Presumably $ 0 < \epsilon < 1$? In which case taking logarithms gives you $k \log (1-\epsilon) < - \log 4n/3,$ and dividing by $\log (1- \epsilon),$ which is negative, gives you $k > \frac{\log 4n/3}{ - \log (1-\epsilon)},$ which is of the required form as long as $\epsilon$ is bounded away from $0$ independently of $n$.

Comment: Thanks, it is indeed solve my question.